# Does kml gx:Track ExtendedData display work with Google Earth Plugin?

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

As you might guess, it's not working for me, and I've been searching for a definitive answer or work-around.  I know it's not supported in Maps.

Here is example kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
  <name>Track</name>
  <open>1</open>
  <Schema name="Info" id="InfoId">
    <gx:SimpleArrayField kml:type="string" kml:name="MyField">
      <displayName>Value</displayName>
    </gx:SimpleArrayField>
  </Schema>
  <Folder>
    <name>Track History</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Track</name>
      <gx:Track>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <when>2012-03-12T05:59:09Z</when>
        <when>2012-03-12T05:59:11Z</when>
        <when>2012-03-12T05:59:13Z</when>
        <gx:coord>-76.1558297472738 43.02432853192255 1544.41929539293</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>-76.136216188444 43.07112543504023 1454.468177223578</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>-76.1190908056531 43.10944870095626 1456.513482289223</gx:coord>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#InfoId">
            <gx:SimpleArrayData kml:name="MyField">
              <gx:value>one</gx:value>
              <gx:value>two</gx:value>
              <gx:value>three</gx:value>
            </gx:SimpleArrayData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
      </gx:Track>
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

This displays as expected in the Earth desktop client.  But when loaded into a browser-based app using the plugin, the `MyField` `ExtendedData` (associated with the `InfoId` schema) does not appear in the balloons associated with the track points.

I figured it might have to do with [scrubbing](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons#scrubbing), so experimented with attaching an event handler to the `balloonopening` event and fetching the balloon content with `getBalloonHtmlUnsafe()`, hoping I could create a new balloon with the unscrubbed content for the track point, but it's not there.  It *is* all there in raw form when fetched with `getKml()`.

Besides creating this simple base-case example, I'm also tried loading it from a string literal with `ge.parseKml()` rather than a network link or `google.earth.fetchKml()`.

So it looks like using the [suggested](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#trackexample) `ExtendedData` technique with `gx:Track` is not supported, or at least not working, in the plugin.  Can someone confirm this, or show me what I'm getting wrong?

Alternatively, I can retrieve a placemark in the above-mentioned balloon event handler that can be used for correctly placing a balloon at the selected track position, but can't find a way to retrieve an array index for the track that I might use to select the data myself from the kml DOM.  The objects appear to be host objects, and thus any special apis into a gx:Track Placemark are not enumerable.  But my real data sets are large (why I'm trying to use `gx:Track`!) and I'd prefer not manipulate all this data in JavaScript anyway.

Oh and and I'm primarily using Win7 and:

```
Google Chrome version: 17.0.963.79 m
Google Earth plugin version: 6.2.1.6014
Google Earth API version: 1.010
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, the Google Earth Plugin only supports a subset of Kml and the GX extensions (e.g. `<gx:Tour>`, `<gx:LatLonQuad>`, etc).

The scrubbing is a red-herring, it only strips elements that are possible vectors for malicious code (iframe, object, etc) it does not strip any Kml or extended elements (as your getKml() test confirmed)...

The long answer is yes, you can display the data, but you would need to parse and format it yourself. Even for the gx elements with some support (i.e. `<gx:Tour>`) one still must do some homespun parsing to access the data.

All in all extended data support is pretty weak in the api, even the most basic un-typed name/value pairs are not really supported.

There is an open feature request for this functionality to be added though, and there are a few work arounds discussed in the thread that may be of some use to you.

http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=16